# How to obtain a factor variable according to two columns. R

Tags: r, dataframe

I nee to create a new column `v4` in this data.frame:

```
v1<-c(1,2,4,7,9,12,34,56,43)
v2<-c(4,4,9,56,73,457,12,12,5585)
v3<-c(7,7,43,124,415,552,552,12525,99)
df<- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

The trick is that in those cases where any of the `v1` value is present in `v2` `v4` must be `1` rest of the cases `v4` must be `2`

So the outcome would be something like this:

```
v1<-c(1,2,4,7,9,12,34,56,43)
v2<-c(4,4,9,56,73,457,12,12,5585)
v3<-c(7,7,43,124,415,552,552,12525,99)
v4<-c(2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2)
df.solution<- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)
```

Comment: Look at your expected output and question, do you think they match?

Comment: `df$v4 <- factor(2 - (df$v1 == df$v2))`

Comment: The desired output you shown is not a `factor` and does not match your description. There isn't any case in which `v1==v2`.

Comment: you are right, is not v1==v2. It's any case that the value of v1 is present in v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample answer but your logic and expected outcome don't match:

**Final answer** after suggested edits and OP's comments:

```
 library(dplyr)
   df %>% 
  mutate(V4=ifelse(v1%in%v2,1,2))
```

Comment: I'd not  suggest a solution involving loading a ton of packages for such a simple task. Invoking all the `tidyverse` is totally unnecessary here.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My question was wrongly formulated. Is not v1==v2. It's any case that the value of v1 is present in v2.

Comment: @nicola Thanks. It's just that I always use the tidyverse!

Comment: @NelsonGon At least load only `dplyr` (don't think loading `ggplot2` is of any help here).

Comment: @nicola Right! I'll edit to reflect that. Out of curiosity, what are some effects of this?

Comment: You force to install a lot of packages to use this solution. Remember that each install might be an issue and make your code less portable. When possible, it's much better to stick with base R and use external packages only when base functionalities are not enough for your goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's something I'll consider henceforth!

Answer (score 3):

Using base R

```
df$v4 <- ifelse(df$v1 %in% df$v2, 1, 2)
```

EDIT: modified answer after the comments in @NelsonGon 's answer